# Rails: Scalable way to sort by most tags in common

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

Please excuse that I am still quite a Rails beginner, but I've got a basic working tagging system using has_many through:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
  [...]
end
```

Given two posts, post1 and post2, I can find which tags they have in common:

```
post1.tags & post2.tags
```

And count how many they have in common:

```
(post1.tags & post2.tags).count
```

Now, the remaining things I am trying to do are a little more complicated:

1. Given a post, get the list of all other posts, ordered by the number of tags the other post has in common with the given post.
2. Get the list of all possible pairs of posts, ordered by number of tags in common. So the pairs with the most tags in common are first, and the pairs with no tags in common are last.

Assuming I have N posts, list 1 should return N-1 posts and list 2 should return N(N-1)/2 posts. So for a simple set:

```
P1: tags A B C D E
P2: tags A   C     F G
P3: tags A   C D   F G
P4: tags   B C D E
```

Func1(P1) should return:
    P4, P3, P2
...since P4 has 4 tags in common with P1, P3 has 3 tags in common, etc.

Func2() should return:
    [P1,P4], [P2,P3], [P1,P3], [P1,P2], [P3,P4], [P2,P4]
...the first two pairs having 4 tags in common, the last pair having only one in common.

I realize for both of these, I could just iterate through, doing some manual counting and sorting in code, but I'm wondering if there is a better, more scalable "Rails" way that takes better advantage of ActiveRecord and SQL?

Any ideas? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use gems like [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) or [rocket_tag](https://github.com/bradphelan/rocket_tag). They have functions for this. If you still want to do it for yourself, look how it is implemented there. Also be careful if you are using postgresql (except for the newest version) and mention all columns in "group by" statement. As far as I know [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) takes care of this issue [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/related.rb).

Comment: Why "be careful if you are using PostgreSQL"? Just curious…

Comment: I went with acts-as-taggable-on. It provides the equivalent of Func1() above, which is good enough.